# How to retrieve from postgres db to dropdown list?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I'm newbie in c# and not familiar with its syntax. Need some help here. I would want to retrieve database data into my dropdownlist. How can i replace the following textbox for dropdownlist?

This is my dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnClick="btnFilterID_Click"></asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the loop to retriev textbox.

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{ 
    txtFname.Text = row["f_name"].ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: have you successfully grabbed data in `dt.Rows`?

Comment: yes, the data successfully grabbed

Comment: checked edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `.cs`

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(row["f_name"].ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: It gave me this error : No overload for method 'Insert' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: @HappyBee sorry, i forgot the value and item, editing my answer to just `.Add`